# (Jquery Pikachoose Jcarousel) png graphic glitch, 'pulsing' on shadows during transition?

Tags: jquery, png, fade

You can see it happening here:

http://www.smooth-media.co.uk/clients/BCD

Comment: Please add some code, not just an external link.

Comment: Its stock Pickachoose plugin, its png's that were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a large amount of divs in your div of class "pika-ani" that have the same background as your picture. If you overlay multiple PNG with a shadow, it will cause the shadow to darken. My guess is that the pulsing occurs when those divs are fading out. Those divs are generated by JCarousel, I would take out your own images that cycle, because I feel like those divs are doubling up with your images.

Comment: I've set them to display: none; but, its still happening =/

Comment: Really? It works fine for me now! Clear your browser's cache and see what happens =)

Comment: I talked to the developer of pikachoose he said it was because there is an overlap when the image hits 50% and is duplicated right before the transition, can be fixed by using fade-out-fade-in options. Other then that there isnt really a fix. Finished version is 
http://www.smooth-media.co.uk/clients/bcd2/

Comment: Yeah, it looks a lot smoother now! Good luck with your website!